# How do we tie an expensive SQL Server query back to the part of C# / EF Core code that generated it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, ef-core-7.0

I'm looking for a reliable strategy that will allow me to relate a performance problem that the Azure portal has highlighted, back to some query in the C# .NET 7 / EF Core 7 app that has generated that query.

In Azure I see that some query is routinely in the top expensive/slow queries

```
SELECT * FROM SomeMassiveTable
```

So, there's no `WHERE` clause - I could start hunting through the codebase for all locations where `db.SomeMassiveTable` is used and chase them out to see if anywhere is enumerating it without applying a `.Where` but I'm curious to know if anyone out there has developed a better approach.

Is there a way of including an intent kind of comment with a query in a way that would show up in a trace?

For example, perhaps when the developer does something like

```
db.WithIntent("Cache the whole SomeMassiveTable locally into redis").SomeMassiveTable.ToList()
```

the Azure portal would complain the top query is:

```
--Cache the whole SomeMassiveTable locally into redis
SELECT * FROM SomeMassiveTable
```

so we could search that comment and find it in the codebase.

How about a way of grabbing a generated query (interceptors) and logging the stack trace if the query has no WHERE keyword present? Or getting some feedback from the (local dev) SQL instance itself that it's just run an expensive query, "and here was the stack trace of the C# side that led to it..."?

I can think of various strategies to try, but I'm trying to find out if this is a problem someone has found a good solution for already

In summary, is there a good, easy to implement, built in approach for tracing problematic queries back to the originating code?

Comment: I'd suggest looking for calls to `ToList()` or `ToArray()` in the code instead - wherever people tried to cover up unparseable LINQ queries, instead of fixing the query or changing the logic

Comment: Indeed, though this is a sizeable codebase and there are several thousand legitimate ToXxx/enumerations. I haven't discovered anything obvious paired up with calls to SomeMassiveTable so far; there are only about 100 references to the context property in the solution I'm checking so it seemed like a good first step.. But I'm perhaps leaning more and more towards an interceptor that tries to grab generated query code and a stacktrace and logs them, then searching that log for queries similar to the problematic one

Comment: Tags will appear in the query itself. The queries can be captured using SQL Server's Extended Events profiler. In fact, there's a live XE session running in all installations to catch the last few events before possible crashes.

Comment: SQL Server's Query store has reports for expensive queries. If the statement includes the comments you'll be able to quickly find the expensive queries.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is possible using [Query Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tags) but that will reveal people are using `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to cover up unparseable LINQ queries instead of fixing them. You can save time by looking for `ToList()` or `ToArray()` in the code.

This was a deliberate action because EF Core throws runtime errors when an unparseable LINQ query is used.

To tag queries in the future, you need to add `.TagWith(someMessage)`, eg:

```
var myLocation = new Point(1, 2);
var nearestPeople = (from f in context.People.TagWith("This is my spatial query!")
                     orderby f.Location.Distance(myLocation) descending
                     select f).Take(5).ToList();
```

That's not as strong a warning or indicator as EF Core's exceptions. It will catch queries that tried to bypass it though.

The tags will be included as comments in the query itself. The query can be logged by using SQL Server [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver16), a lightweight monitoring system that tracks all events, including query statements. SSMS shows  such events using the [XEvents Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-ssms-xe-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) extension.

The comments will probably appear in [Query Store reports on expensive queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Can one really access the tag comment in sql trace/events etc when running the real query? Since i guess sql server parses away comments

Comment: @siggemannen the comments are still part of the query text and will appear in Extended Events, SQL Server Profiler and Activity Monitor.

Comment: I'm not so sure. If you run this: -- testing comments

select top 3 x.*
from sys.traces t
cross apply sys.fn_trace_gettable(t.path, null) x
where textdata is not null
order by x.StartTime desc; the comment part doesn't appear. I think only comments in the middle of the query do. The comments do appear when you do dbcc inputbuffer(#sessionID#)

Comment: @siggemannen I'm not talking about traces. Traces are an old (introduced in 2005) and  deprecated feature, completely different from XEs or the profiler. In fact, the `fn_trace_gettable ` doc page warns against using this. `This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server`. The deprecation notice is going back almost a decade although the online docs only go back to 2016. XEs were introduced in 2010 (2008 R2) and reached feature-parity with the profiler in 2012

Comment: Isn't profiler using the same technology :)

Comment: As I said, XEs replaced profiler in 2012. Besides, are you sure you're looking at the *correct* events? SQL Statement events capture the actual lines or expressions *inside* a script or stored procedure. You'd have to check Batch events to see the entire script

Comment: Alright. I just tested XE and comment does indeed appear there!

Comment: It appears in SQL Server profiler as well. `sys.traces` returns *all* the running traces. That doesn't mean all of those are tracking all events and details, all of the time. The *default* system trace tracks only specific system-level events. Capturing statements is expensive and can impact the performance of the entire server

Comment: The issue with this is that you manually have to annotate everything with `TagWith`; AFAIK there's no global way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Another option worthy to try is [EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.TagWithCallSite Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tagwithcallsite?view=efcore-7.0) that creates a tag with source file name and line where method was called. Examples can be found [here](https://thirty25.com/posts/2021/12/tagging-query-with-ef-core).

```
public static IQueryable<T> TagWithSource<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable,
    string tag = default,
    [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0,
    [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "",
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [CallerArgumentExpression("queryable")]
    string argument = "")
{
    // argument could be multiple lines with whitespace so let's normalize it down to one line
    var trimmedLines = string.Join(
        string.Empty,
        argument.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(i => i.Trim())
    );

    var tagContent = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag)
        ? default
        : tag + Environment.NewLine;

    tagContent += trimmedLines + Environment.NewLine + $" at {memberName}  - {filePath}:{lineNumber}";

    return queryable.TagWith(tagContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To tie all EF Core SQL executions back to the calling methods, you can use an [interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors). The benefit of this solution is that you don't need to explicitly add anything on every `IQueryable` in your project, this will implicitly work for all of them:

```
public class AppendCallingStackTraceDbCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override int NonQueryExecuted(
        DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, int result)
    {
        AppendCallingStackTrace(command);

        return result;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> NonQueryExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AppendCallingStackTrace(command);

        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        AppendCallingStackTrace(command);

        return result;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AppendCallingStackTrace(command);

        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<object> ScalarExecuting(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result)
    {
        AppendCallingStackTrace(command);

        return result;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<object>> ScalarExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AppendCallingStackTrace(command);

        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Security", "CA2100:Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities", Justification = "Appends a comment, thus cannot cause a vulnerability")]
    private static void AppendCallingStackTrace(DbCommand command)
    {
        var stack = new StackTrace(true);

        // append a comment to the SQL to be executed, containing stack trace details
        command.CommandText +=
            $"{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}/*********************{Environment.NewLine} *"
            + string.Join(
                $"{Environment.NewLine} * ",
                stack.GetFrames()
                    .Select(frame => new { frame, method = frame.GetMethod() })
                    .Select(@t =>
                        $"{@t.method?.DeclaringType?.Name}.{@t.method?.Name}: {t.frame.GetFileLineNumber()}"))
            + $"{Environment.NewLine}*********************/";
    }
}
```

Registered when you add your `DbContext`:

```
services.AddDbContext<RepaymentsDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
{
    optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new[]
    {
        new AppendCallingStackTraceDbCommandInterceptor(),
    });
});
```

Customise the `AppendCallingStackTrace` method to taste!